# Glob that includes a folder's subfolders, but not the actual subfolder (Gulp)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

I wish to write a glob (in a Gulp file) that matches all files in a folder's subfolders, like this:

`/somefolder/**/*.somefile`

but at the same time **exclude** the files in the parent folder:

`/somefolder/*.somefile`

(My rationale with this is to target template partials (in subfolders), but not the actual templates in the parent folder.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `/somefolder/*/**/*.somefile`.

This will match any `.somefile` file that appears *inside of* `/somefolder/*`. The glob `/somefolder/*` would match both folders and files that are directly inside `/somefolder` but the criterion "*inside of* `/somefolder/*`" will eliminate the files that are directly inside `/somefolder` since from a filesystem standpoint a file cannot contain a file, only folders can. (I've tested it, and it works.)